# How to remove transitions from title motion adjustments in Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere, editing, animation, effects

I am using some motion adjustments (Effect Controls) on title clips placed on top of my video layer in Premiere Pro CC 2015. I change the position of the clips (names) and also change the scaling per 5 frames. But I want a jump effect from one keyframe (of position and scale) to another (after the 5 frames). I don't need a smooth transition.

In other words, I don't need animation but something like different title clips without the need to make them. Can this be done with the motion adjustments or will they always animate between the keyframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set temporal interpolation to `Hold` as [seen](http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/premiere-pro-tutorial-setting-keyframe-interpolation/) below:

[image]

Comment: You have no idea how helpful it was. I'm new to video editing and this... you just saved my life man... I was thinking of making new titles for all positions, and for all places where I use names. Thanks a bunch!